# Lookup duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do a lookup to fetch target id from table (s:

```
source_id      source_name        target_name
1              abc                def
2              def                def
3              ghi                jkl
4              jkl                mno
```

I am using:

```
select a.*,b.source_id as parent_id
from table a
left join table b
on a.source_name=b.target_name;
```

But I get duplicates after this join when I apply on bigger data. Please help me on what could be the reason here. I need the count(*) of table before and after the join same with the target_id alone inserted.

Thanks!

Comment: You are not getting "duplicates".  Your result set correct shows that your `join` has multiple matches.  You have not shown the sample data or explained what you want to do in this case, so your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I speculate that your `join` conditions are backwards:

```
select a.*, b.source_id as parent_id
from table a left join
     table b
     on b.source_name = a.target_name;
```

The `source_name` looks unique in your table, not the `target_name`.

That said, you should not be depending on `name` at all.  Your "target" or "parent" column should refer to the `id`.  So, your data model looks like it could be fixed up.